# how to draw Square button in iOS under navigation bar

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have this code and I want to have my button **as a square,** and also **under the navigation bar**,would you plase help me

Thanks in advance!

**I want to have my button as a square**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];



int rows = 13, columns = 4;
UIView *buttonView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, 70*columns, 70*rows)];
for (int y = 0; y < rows; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < columns; x++) {
        UIButton * button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(70 * x, 28 * y, 70, 28);

        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [buttonView addSubview: button];

    }
 }

// Center the view which contains your buttons
CGPoint centerPoint = buttonView.center;
centerPoint.x = self.view.center.x;
buttonView.center = centerPoint;
[self.view addSubview:buttonView];    

}


-(void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)button
{
NSLog(@"button %u -- frame: %@", button.tag, NSStringFromCGRect(button.frame));
}
```

**Edit 2**

my error when I using border

```
    [button.layer setBorderWidth:1.0]; 
    [button.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting your button of size 70x28, so if you want a button 70x70, you have to change button.frame = CGRectMake(70*x, 70*y, 70, 70), this way you will have square buttons.

Also, are you sure this is a NavigationBar or just a Toolbar? If you use NavigationController which uses navigationBar, Apple's own SDK will not allow you to easily draw over it.

In any case in your case, just start drawing your buttons from y = 44 down and you won't have buttons overlap the toolbar.

Comment: Also be sure to use UIButton * button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]; instead of UIButton * button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];. RoundedRect will round the corners of your button, while Custom will keep the corners sharp.

Comment: yeah @Jeremy1026 is correct, if you use default button you will get button with rounded corners with, UIButtonTypeCustom you can do what ever you want...

Comment: @Jeremy1026 thanks for reply! do when I'm using UIButtonTypeCustom, then I don't have a border how can I set borde?

Comment: @Ladislav thanks for reply! do when I'm using UIButtonTypeCustom, then I don't have a border how can I set borde?

Comment: @Jeremy1026 How can I set border?

Comment: @justin try using [button.layer setBorderWidth:1.0];         [button.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

Comment: @Jeremy1026 I don't know why I have error I put my error picture above

Comment: @justin Import the QuartzCore framework into your project and QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h into your file.

Comment: @Jeremy1026 thanks alot it was perfect, do you know what should i do if I want to add number for each square from 1 to 52 .. ? in center of each square?

Comment: You should just do [button setTitle:@"1" forControlState:UIControlStateNormal];

Comment: @Ladislav I have an error with this code, should I use forControlState: or forState ? but I will get 1 for all 52 buttons

Answer (score 1):

Define an integer variable and set this as button title

```
int rows = 13, columns = 4;
int number=1;
UIView *buttonView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.f,44, 70*columns, 70*rows)];
for (int y = 0; y < rows; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < columns; x++) {
        UIButton * button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(75 * x, 75 * y, 70, 70);
        button.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
        [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",number] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        button.tag=number;
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [buttonView addSubview: button];
        number++;
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you to move to next screen. Button.tag gives the exact button you have selected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
int rows = 13, columns = 4;  
UIView *buttonView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.f,44, 70*columns, 70*rows)];
for (int y = 0; y < rows; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < columns; x++) {
        UIButton * button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(75 * x, 75 * y, 70, 70);
        button.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [buttonView addSubview: button];

    }
}

// Center the view which contains your buttons
CGPoint centerPoint = buttonView.center;
centerPoint.x = self.view.center.x;
buttonView.center = centerPoint;
[self.view addSubview:buttonView];
```

For using layer property you need to add QuartzCore.framework in your project.

Comment: thanks alot it was perfect, do you know what should i do if I want to add number for each square from 1 to 52 .. ? in center of each square?